# Trac: users not visible

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, trac

I'm new to Trac (and to stackoverflow ;-) and I've finally managed to install the latest version of Trac (1.2.1) on my Ubuntu 16.04. It runs on Apache with a MySQL databse, and I installed it with the help of this tutorial: https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/08/06/ubuntu-16-04-install-trac/

I changed one thing in the trac.ini: `restrict_owner: true`, in order to get a "assign-to"-drop-down list with all the registered users.

When I create a new user with `htdigest /var/lib/trac/test/.htdigest "test" newusername`, I can normally log in with that user on Trac. The problem is that this user does not appear in the drop-down list. I tried to give the user all permissions (like create ticket, modify ticket etc.), but this doesn't help.

Does anyone has an idea how to solv this? It would help a lot!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users that haven't yet logged-in to the project won't appear in the list. It is explained [here](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTickets#Assign-toasDrop-DownList).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! 
I have read this page and I think that I have done all the necessary steps, but still - it doesn't work.

First, I created the user with 'sudo htdigest /var/lib/trac/ebner/.htdigest "testsystem" testuser' 
Then I added the necessary permission with 'trac-admin /var/lib/trac/testsystem/ permission add testuser TICKET_MODIFY'

Now I'm logged in with the testuser and the only person in the assign-to field I can sellect is the admin.

Do you have any further ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does `trac-admin /var/lib/trac/testsystem session list` output?

Comment: It shows that admin and testusers last visit was today, and a '1' after their username

Comment: Suddenly, the testuser appears in the dropdown list. But when I create another user, I still have the same problem as before... (the new user does not appeat in the session list!)

Comment: Okay, I think that is because the users are cached. Please try restarting your webserver after adding a user and let me know if the user then appears in the session list.

Comment: thanks for this idea, but I have solved this problem with installing the AccountManagerPlugin

Comment: Glad it is working. I tested the behavior to be sure. Running the command like `trac-admin trac-env session add user1:1` makes `user1` appear in the select list immediately. This is with TracStandalone, though I don't expect another web server would behave differently. The reason it works is the cache is [invalidated by the "session add" command](https://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.2.1/trac/web/session.py?marks=501#L486). To be sure, I commented out that line and confirmed that without the cache invalidation `user1` does *not* immediately appear. I suspect caching in your browser.